# Anchor Tag doesn't work because of animation

Tags: wordpress, anchor, visual-composer

**Goal:** I need to set anchor tags for the wordpress-site: http://joy-academy.eu/programs/
I am using Visual Composer and there is some animation.

**Problem:** If I try to set an anchor tag, it scrolls to the right place but does not show the previous parts that are animated like here:http://joy-academy.eu/programs/#example or if I use a Plugin "scroll to Id", it just scrolls to a random place, like for example here: http://joy-academy.eu/programs/#cc

**Details:** The Wordpress Theme is "Zyen". Ref: https://themeforest.net/item/zeyn-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/8848292

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I see that your site is using the Zeyn theme. 
That's the first place to look for coding style changes. Here's a demo example doing what I think you are hoping to achieve.  http://djavaweb.com/selector.php?theme=zeyn-classic

This means don't use the button for an anchor. So, use the Extra id in the rows to correspond with the anchor link (#example).
Here's the directions to do this; just start *after* the steps about the menu items. 
http://kb.detheme.com/knowledge-base/zeyn-faq-one-page-navigation/

Comment: Mary, did this work? And don't forget to validate/accept if the answer helped you.